# Yii2 не работает сайт

Tags: php, yii2, centos

Есть некий ресурс на Yii2. После авторизации на котором, происходит бесконечный редирект на 302 код /forbieden, в какую сторону смотреть? На сервере установлен Apache, error log пустой, ранее все работало

Comment: Невозможно дать ответ на данный вопрос. Вариантов куча. "ранее все работало" - что делали перед тем, как перестало работать?

Answer (score 0):

В одном из контроллеров у Вас скорее всего стоит перенаправление.

Ищите в их коде вызов данной функции

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller#redirect()-detail

с указанным кодом